# Online transactions: which one is safer - credit card or netbanking?

Tags: banks, money

There are various modes of online transaction, such as through entering credit card details, and through netbanking. Which one is safer? [it seems there are some risks with credit card mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233076/what-can-be-done-with-credit-or-debit-card-informations-asked-by-websites#) mode but is netbanking safer than that?

I seacrched the google but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Can you define "netbanking" for us as a payment method?

Comment: There aren't many risks outlined at that link, it sounds pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the protection around using credit cards is legal (will vary slightly across different countries). Due to the nature of the transaction, when you use a credit card, your recipient is not accepting your cash, but the card provider's -- who will in turn charge you back. If you're victim of fraud, you can simply call the payment provider and ask them to cancel the transaction. Unless they suspect you in any meaningful way (i.e. if you do this often), they'll just do it without asking questions. This is why you should keep an eye on your statements to react quickly if need be. Also make sure you immediately report lost or stolen cards (credit and debit).

(btw: This is an excellent answer to the other question you posed, much better written than mine: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/233078/200347)

This is safer than debit card from a liability perspective since with a debit card you are paying with your own money and in case of fraud you'll need to make the recipient return the cash or have your bank cover the expense -- if they agree it's fraud and you couldn't have avoided it (which is variable).

Netbanking is whatever banks want to call their system. Could be a way to use pre-paid credit cards, a way to execute transfers, a way to electronically transfer cash (like paypal), etc. So unless you have further details about what netbanking is for you, it's not possible to draw a conclusion.